# IBM Watson Machine Learning hand-written digits sample notebook authentication error

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud, watson-ml

When working through section 6.1 of the **Recognition of hand-written digits with IBM Watson Machine Learning** notebook, calling the Watson Machine Learning REST API to get the list of published models using:

```
GET /v3/wml_instances/{instance_id}/published_models
```

endpoint, there is a authorization (401) error with the following response text:

```
{"trace":"-1xmid60eblabs","errors":[{"code":"invalid_token_format","message":"Invalid token format. Bearer token format should be used.","target":{"type":"header","name":"Authorization"}}]}
```

The previous REST API call in the notebook to get the instance details using the authorization token returned from the `/v3/identity/token` endpoint worked ok.

Looks like an error in the notebook. Did the API authorization scheme change breaking the notebook?

Comment: Hi Tim. Can you please update your question with a link to the section that you are referencing? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Bill, this is a community notebook that gets linked from the Manage control pane from a Bluemix Watson Machine Learning control panel. Links are user/instance specific. In parallel, I've been in touch with the team and they've just updated this and a couple of other affected community notebooks for ML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This endpoint in the REST API appears to be expecting authentication of the form `Authorization: <type> <credentials>` per W3C in [HTTP 1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945)

I updated the notebook code to add the type in the Authorization field of the header:

```
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + mltoken}
```

The rest of the Watson Machine Learning API calls to create the online deployment and score new data use the same  header in the notebook and all execute correctly.

Comment: This fix has been applied to the following notebooks as of 8/17/17
  Recognition of hand-written digits with IBM Watson Machine Learning,
  Predictive modeling with IBM Watson Machine Learning using Python, and
  Predictive modeling with IBM Watson Machine Learning with Scala